# Bonding two interfaces

Tags: networking, ip, bonding

I'm trying to simulate **bonding** between two interfaces  `eth0` and `eth1`. So basicly, I need these two interfaces to be on the **same subnet**.

My question here is: How can I achieve this?

Comment: You haven't specified which OS you are using or what type of bonding you want (link aggregation, active/passive, load balancing etc)

Comment: I'm using **Ubuntu**, and I want a **link aggregation** bonding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man8/ifenslave.8.html

> ```
>  # modprobe bonding
>  # ifconfig bond0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.0.0
>  # ifenslave bond0 eth0 eth1
> ```

however, you have to be sure the same bonding protocol is also set on remote equipment.

There are [seven modes](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/static/linux-ethernet-bonding-driver-howto.php) for bonding configuration.

These affect which non failed interface will be used to receive and transmit packets.

On network equipment side, you also specify that port `Fe0/10` and `Fe0/11` (for instance, in a pseudo Cisco notation) are part of a bond.

Network equipment will discover the IP, the same way it discovers the usual link.

You might also be interested in this [documentation](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/bonding), in French.

Comment: How can the router identify bond0 address ?